# Equivalent of LIMIT and OFFSET of SQL in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   id type city
0   2    d    H
1   7    c    J
2   7    x    Y
3   2    o    G
4   6    i    F
5   5    b    E
6   6    v    G
7   8    u    L
8   1    g    L
9   8    k    U
```

I would like to get the similar output using pandas as in SQL command:

```
select id,type
from df
order by type desc
limit 4
offset 2
```

The required result is:

```
   id type
0   8    u
1   2    o
2   8    k
3   6    i
```

I tried to follow the official tutorial https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html#top-n-rows-with-offset

```
df.nlargest(4+2, columns='type').tail(4)
```

But, this fails.

How to solve the problem?

**UPDATE**

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as pdsql
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
df = pd.read_csv('http://ourairports.com/data/airports.csv')


q = '''
select id,type
from df
order by type desc
limit 4
offset 2
'''

print(pysqldf(q))

```
       id           type
0    6525  small_airport
1  322127  small_airport
2    6527  small_airport
3    6528  small_airport
```
````

Using pandas:

```
print(df.sort_values('type', ascending=False).iloc[2:2+4][['id','type']])
           id           type
43740   37023  small_airport
43739   37022  small_airport
24046  308281  small_airport
24047  309587  small_airport
```

Comment: How do you define 'airports' table in the updated code?

Comment: sorry, airport is same as df.

Comment: Please update the the code to reflect this.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why they are sorted that way for you tbh. Once the df is sorted   by `type` using `sort_values`, running `t[t.id == 6525].index`, which is your first result gives me the index 23642 (this having reset the index).

Comment: I just ran the code in **UPDATE**, it gives me first id 6525 and type small_airport.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, integer location, where iloc starting index is the 'offset' and ending index is incremented by 'limit':

```
df.sort_values('type', ascending=False).iloc[2:6]
```

Output:

```
   id type city
7   8    u    L
3   2    o    G
9   8    k    U
4   6    i    F
```

And you can add `reset_index` to clean up indexing.

```
print(df.sort_values('type', ascending=False).iloc[2:6].reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
   id type city
0   8    u    L
1   2    o    G
2   8    k    U
3   6    i    F
```

## Update let's sort by type and index:

```
df.index.name = 'index'
df[['id','type']].sort_values(['type','index'], ascending=[False,True]).iloc[2:6]
```

Output:

```
   index      id           type
0      3    6525  small_airport
1      5  322127  small_airport
2      6    6527  small_airport
3      7    6528  small_airport
```

Comment: I tried this method with the dataframe `df = pd.read_csv('http://ourairports.com/data/airports.csv')`  but I got the different result than SQL. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `ascending=False`, and use [`.loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to slice the result (having reset the index) with the rows and columns of interest:

```
offset = 2
limit = 4
(df.sort_values(by='type', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
               .loc[offset : offset+limit-1, ['id','type']])

   id type
2   8    u
3   2    o
4   8    k
5   6    i
```

Comment: does this keep the order same as in SQL if we have same type values for different id?

Comment: Sorry not sure of what you mean @astro123, could you give me an example so we can check?

Comment: I have updated the question,  I have tested one case of pandas and it gives the different answer than SQL.